# STORAGE_WRITE_API Method uses for Batch mode or Streaming Mode?

Tags: java, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am using `STORAGE_WRITE_API` method in **Dataflow** for writing data into BigQuery through Batch Pipeline. That is causing issues and sometimes it gets stuck and does not load data into Biquery. It works with small tables but with the large table, it starts giving issues without throwing any errors.

I tried the same code with `Default` write method and it run properly with small as well as large tables.

So I wanted to know the `STORAGE_WRITE_API` method for BigQuery is recommended for Batch Pipeline or not?

```
rows.apply(BigQueryIO.writeTableRows()
        .withJsonSchema(tableJsonSchema)
        .to(String.format("project:SampleDataset.%s", tableName))
        .withWriteDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND)
        .withCreateDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.CreateDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED)
        .withMethod(BigQueryIO.Write.Method.STORAGE_WRITE_API)
);
```

Comment: Yes it's recommended for batch. It can also be used in streaming.
Can you give us more details about issues with large files please ?

Comment: Please check on BigQuery if you are not reaching any quota. It's important to note that file loads can be more beneficial/cheaper in a lot of cases, if you can keep it under the quota: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#load_jobs (it is the default for batch jobs).

Answer (score 1):

The `STORAGE_WRITE_API` is recommended for `batch` and `streaming` according to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/write-api) :

> The BigQuery Storage Write API is a unified data-ingestion API for
> BigQuery. It combines streaming ingestion and batch loading into a
> single high-performance API. You can use the Storage Write API to
> stream records into BigQuery in real time or to batch process an
> arbitrarily large number of records and commit them in a single atomic
> operation.
>
> Advantages of using the Storage Write API Exactly-once delivery
> semantics. The Storage Write API supports exactly-once semantics
> through the use of stream offsets. Unlike the tabledata.insertAll
> method, the Storage Write API never writes two messages that have the
> same offset within a stream, if the client provides stream offsets
> when appending records.
>
> Stream-level transactions. You can write data to a stream and commit
> the data as a single transaction. If the commit operation fails, you
> can safely retry the operation.
>
> Transactions across streams. Multiple workers can create their own
> streams to process data independently. When all the workers have
> finished, you can commit all of the streams as a transaction.
>
> Efficient protocol. The Storage Write API is more efficient than the
> older insertAll method because it uses gRPC streaming rather than REST
> over HTTP. The Storage Write API also supports binary formats in the
> form of protocol buffers, which are a more efficient wire format than
> JSON. Write requests are asynchronous with guaranteed ordering.
>
> Schema update detection. If the underlying table schema changes while
> the client is streaming, then the Storage Write API notifies the
> client. The client can decide whether to reconnect using the updated
> schema, or continue to write to the existing connection.
>
> Lower cost. The Storage Write API has a significantly lower cost than
> the older insertAll streaming API. In addition, you can ingest up to 2
> TB per month for free.

There are many advantages for batch and streaming.

For batch mode, it's more efficient than `BATCH_LOAD` method.

You need to check from all the possible logs to understand this weird behaviour :

- job log in Dataflow UI
- worker log in Dataflow UI
- Diagnostics tab in Dataflow UI
- Cloud Logging with filter on `dataflow_step`

Use the latest [apache beam](https://beam.apache.org/get-started/downloads/) version if possible `2.43.0`